# Python retorna None ao utilizar método "sort" em lista

Tags: python

Preciso criar uma lista que será criada por números inseridos pelo usuário e, ao inserir números repetidos, esse número não deve ser adicionado. Por fim, o programa deve apresentar a lista com os números em ordem crescente. Fiz o seguinte porém apresenta ao final como resultado `None`. Além disso, estou tendo dificuldades de inserir uma checagem dentro do laço para pedir outra resposta caso o usuário não digite 's' ou 'n' em 'Deseja continuar?'.

```
numeros = list()

while True:
    n = int(input('Digite um número:'))
    if n in numeros:
        n = int(input('O número já foi digitado! Digite outro:'))
    else:
        numeros.append(n)
    r = input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]:')
    if r.upper() == 'N':
        break

print(numeros.sort())
```

Comment: Seu algoritmo parece certo. O problema é que o método `sort` das listas simplesmente modifica (ordenando-a) a lista e não retorna nada. Se você quiser que a lista seja devidamente ordenada **e** retornada, utilize a função `sorted`, assim: `print(sorted(numeros))`.

Comment: Quanto a checagem, você poderia tentar algo do tipo: `while not r in 'SsNn':
 r = input('Entrada Inválida. Digite S ou N: ')`